# SSE comparison returns vector of NANs

Tags: sse, simd

I am trying something like this:

```
__m128 cA = _mm_set_ps1(-2.0f);
__m128 cB = _mm_set_ps1(2.0f);
__m128 df = _mm_cmpgt_ps(cA, cB);
```

In this case `df` returns with zeros.

But if I do:

```
__m128 cA = _mm_set_ps1(2.0f);
__m128 cB = _mm_set_ps1(-2.0f);
__m128 df = _mm_cmpgt_ps(cA, cB);
```

It returns all `-nan`  .Is is expected behaviour? If it is,how do I evaluate those nans?

Using Intel CPU,MS VisualStudio 2017

Comment: @MarcGlisse  "Compare packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements in a and b for greater-than, and store the results in dst."  I assume it returns mask.No?

Comment: A mask of all set bits is also a negative nan if read as a float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SIMD compares produce a mask.  All-one bits is the bit-pattern for `-NaN`.  All-zero bits is the bit-pattern for `+0.0`

They're not intended to be interpreted as `float`.  Use them with `_mm_movemask_ps`, blends, or things like `_mm_and_ps`.

e.g. `_mm_and_ps( vec, cmp_result)` zeros the elements where the compare was false.  You can use this to do a conditional add by zeroing some input elements before an add.

---

For more about how to use SIMD, look up a guide/tutorial.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info